# calculate document weight using machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

lets say that i have n number of documents(resumes) in my list, and i want to weigh the each document(resume) of same category with Job description.txt as reference. i want to weigh the document as per below. My question is there any other approach to weigh the document in this kind of scenario? Thanks in advance.

Plan of action :

a) get resumes (eg. 10) related to same category (eg. java)

b) get bag of words from all the docs

for:

```
c) each document get features names by using TFIDF vectorizor scores

d) now I have list of featured words in a list 

e) now compare these features in "Job Discription" Bag of words

f) now count the score for the document by adding the columns and weigh the document
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Pleas share some code that you've tried out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from the question is that you are looking to grade the resumes(documents) by seeing how similar they are to the job description document. One approach that can be used is to convert all documents to a  TFIDF matrix including the job description. Each document can be seen as vector in the word space. Once you have created the TFIDF matrix, you can calculate the similarity between two documents using cosine similarity.

There are additional things that you should do like removing stopwords, lemmatizing and encoding. Additionaly you may also want to make use of n-grams.

You can refer [this book](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/) as well for more information.

**EDIT**:

Adding some setup code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

# to remove punctuations
translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

# some sample documents
resumes = ["Executive Administrative Assistant with over 10 years of experience providing thorough and skillful support to senior executives.",
"Experienced Administrative Assistant, successful in project management and systems administration.",
"10 years of administrative experience in educational settings; particular skill in establishing rapport with people from diverse backgrounds.",
"Ten years as an administrative support professional in a corporation that provides confidential case work.",
"A highly organized and detail-oriented Executive Assistant with over 15 years' experience providing thorough and skillful administrative support to senior executives.",
"More than 20 years as a knowledgeable and effective psychologist working with individuals, groups, and facilities, with particular emphasis on geriatrics and the multiple psychopathologies within that population.",
"Ten years as a sales professional with management experience in the fashion industry.",
"More than 6 years as a librarian, with 15 years' experience as an active participant in school-related events and support organizations.",
"Energetic sales professional with a knack for matching customers with optimal products and services to meet their specific needs. Consistently received excellent feedback from customers.",
"More than six years of senior software engineering experience, with strong analytical skills and a broad range of computer expertise.",
"Software Developer/Programmer with history of productivity and successful project outcomes."]

job_doc = ["""Executive Administrative with a knack for matching and effective psychologist with particular emphasis on geriatrics"""]

# combine the two
_all = resumes+job_doc

# convert each to spacy document
docs= [nlp(document) for document in _all]

# lemmatizae words, remove stopwords, remove punctuations
docs_pp = [' '.join([token.lemma_.translate(translator) for token in docs if not token.is_stop]) for docs in docs]

# get tfidf matrix
tfidf_vec = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vec.fit_transform(docs_pp).todense()

# calculate similarity
cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[-1,], tfidf_matrix[:-1,])
```